# How to search base on multiple parameters

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I'm having problem with my search queries.I tried to search the database base on user input and as well restrict them from seeing certain details but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

here is my query:

```
if(isset($_GET['search_term']))
{


    $search_term = $_GET['search_term'];
    $ind = 'IND';
    if(empty($search_term)){
     echo '<div class="alert-warning" id="alert_message">Error: enter your query parameter.</div>'; 
    }else{

     $query = "SELECT * FROM [info].[dbo].[customer] WHERE cust_no LIKE '%$search_term'  OR branch LIKE $search_term AND cust_type != 'BUS' AND cust_type != 'GRP' AND cust_type != 'MGM' AND cust_type != 'INT'" ;
   $check = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);  

   #checks if the search was made
                        if($check == false){
                             die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                        }

                        #checks if the search brought some row and if it is one only row
                        if(sqlsrv_has_rows($check) != 1){
                               echo '<div class="alert-warning" id="alert_message">Error: no data found for this query.</div>';


                        }
```

Comment: Please write more, what you want, and what you get. Maybe this  `$query = "SELECT * FROM [info].[dbo].[customer] WHERE (cust_no LIKE '%$search_term'  OR branch LIKE $search_term) AND cust_type != 'BUS' AND cust_type != 'GRP' AND cust_type != 'MGM' AND cust_type != 'INT'" ;`

Answer (score 0):

You should not combine `OR` and `AND` like that, it will not do what you expect and match a lot more.

You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [info].[dbo].[customer] WHERE 
  (cust_no LIKE '%$search_term' OR branch LIKE $search_term)  // are these conditions even valid sql?
  AND cust_type != 'BUS' 
  AND cust_type != 'GRP' 
  AND cust_type != 'MGM' 
  AND cust_type != 'INT'
```

**Note:** You should also look into prepared statements to get rid of the sql injection problem you have now.

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll do that immediately. Thanks also for the code. Have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  [ info ] .[ dbo ] .[ customer ] 
WHERE (
    cust_no LIKE '%sss%' 
    OR branch LIKE '%sss%'
  ) 
  AND cust_type != 'BUS' 
  AND cust_type != 'GRP' 
  AND cust_type != 'MGM' 
  AND cust_type != 'INT'
```

Comment: Thanks guys, you people rock. @Gaurav, Thanks so much. It worked like magic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM [info].[dbo].[customer] WHERE cust_no LIKE '". %$search_term ."'  OR branch LIKE  '". %$search_term% ."' AND cust_type != 'BUS' AND cust_type != 'GRP' AND cust_type != 'MGM' AND cust_type != 'INT'" ;
```